# xalan xslt processor - trouble with schemaLocation

Tags: xml, namespaces, xalan

i haven't quite verified this, but we are using xalan xslt processor and
looks like it is doesn't work very well unless we remove 
xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.xyz.com/some.xsd" and some more name space attributes.

i want to know if this is due to https or is it just a bug with xalan that we have to live with or is their an option that we can use to make the processor ignore schemalocation attribute.

we have huge xml files and currently we have to open each and remove the above
mentioned string before calling xalan processor

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you can either remove them or try using "CDATA".

Comment: thanks for the reply. are there any better/faster xsl processors?